# Finding Minimum Hamming Distance From Zero

Tags: coding-theory

[image]

Can anyone give me a shor explanation why in this picture, they started of the last 0 from first vector and why what is noted with a is 8?

```
C = {01010101, 10101010, 00000000, 11111111}
```

And the question was to:

```
compute d(C)  = min ({Hd(v,w) / v, w belongs to C});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hamming distance is the number of bits that are different between two vectors (or, equivalently, the number of $1$s in the XOR sum). I think that they didn't mean "we start from this particular zero bit" but rather that arrows are between the wole vectors, to say that the hamming distance between the first and the second one is $8$ since each bits are different, the distance between the first vector and the third is $4$ (one half of the $0$ bits are the same), and so on. The arrow could have start from any other bit as well, this is not significant.

Comment: I see. Also, I see that d(C) = 4. Do you have any ideea how they got this result? I tried to apply anything that is related with hamming distance, and I just can't get that 4.

Comment: By definition of the minimum distance, you have to find the minimum of $d(u,v)$ when $u$ and $v$ range over $C$, where $d$ is the Hamming distance. In real life, you dont often actually compute it by hand for every such possible couples, but here you only have 4 elements in your code. This is exactly what is done in your image : they compute the distance between every words in the code, that is noted $a,b,c,d,e=8,4,4,4,4$. You can see that the minimum is indeed $4$.

Comment: Now is clear. Thank you a lot!